# Why did Einstein's teacher say that Einstein's presence alone undermined his authority?

Tags: biographical-details, einstein, physicists

Based on the excellent answer from @njuffa in the post [Is it true that Albert Einstein was kicked out of high school due to his "peacefulness"?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15170/is-it-true-that-albert-einstein-was-kicked-out-of-high-school-due-to-his-peacef) there is a quote from what the "home-room teacher" who said to Einstein:

> Your presence alone ruins the respect I receive in class.

Why did the teacher say this to Einstein. What was the context or the situation? Did Einstein undermine the authority of the teacher in some way? Or did he expose the teacher's inability?

Comment: For context: I speak American English. The historic German term that I translated as "home-room teacher" is *Ordinarius*, and the modern German word would be *Klassenlehrer*. This is a teacher with administrative and general welfare responsibilities for a group of students. I believe (but am not certain) that the British English equivalent would be "form teacher".

Comment: That's correct, I speak German and "form teacher" is exactly "Klassenlehrer", the teacher who has responsibility for a particular class in a school.